# One to many relationship with a pointer to "current" in the 'many side'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I'm writing an asp.net core web API project.
I have a 'one to many' relationship from 'User' to 'Plans' which is working fine.
The thing is, I want to have a 'current' entry in the 'many' side, meaning in addition to the list of all plans stored in the user entity - I want to add a single plan that states the current plan
What is the best way to do this?
My plan class:

```cs
public class Plan
    {
        public Plan() { }

        public Plan(string name, string description, User user)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Description = description;
            this.Workouts = new HashSet<Workout>();
            this.User = user;
            this.UserId = user.Id;
            this.status = PlanStatus.UnStarted;
        }
        [Key]
        public int PlanId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public PlanStatus status;
        public virtual ICollection<Workout> Workouts { get; set; }
    }
```

PlanStatus Enum:

```cs
public enum PlanStatus
{
    Unstarted,
    InProgress,
    Completed
}
```

My User class:

```cs
public class User : IdentityUser
    {

        public User() {
        }
        public User(string name, string email)
        {
            this.UserName = name;
            this.Email = email;
            this.Plans = new HashSet<Plan>();
            this.Exercises = new HashSet<Exercise>();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<Plan> Plans { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    }
```

One way I thought of is to add 'currentPlanId' to the User class, but that requires maintenance..
The other way is to check all the Plans that belong to a User and check their 'PlanStatus' - if it's 'inProgress' that's the current plan (there should be only one plan at a time with that status)

Which is better? or is there another way?

Comment: _" but that requires maintenance"_ - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: _"Which is better?"_ - What are your criteria for quality?

Comment: I mean it's not a built-in foreign key - so if say the plan is deleted - we need to actually go and change the currentPlanId in the related User.
Not much maintenance but it doesn't feel so right to 'think of the user class' when editing or deleting a plan

Comment: Thinking about it: you are also losing "historical" data about the plans' status. _Maybe_ those should in fact be a whole separate table? Then you could know exactly which plan was (or is) the current one at what time for what user ... But maybe that's overkill. Don't know your requirements.

Comment: I do record the Exercises (which is a seperate table that has one-to-many with Workout table, that has one-to-many with Plan) So that's enough for my matters.
But I allow a plan to 'start' even if the user didn't start any exercise in it... so that won't help
Thanks for your input!

Comment: Sounds like it's a many-to-many between a user and a plan but you have it as a one-to-many which is why you have to change the value in the FK field. Fildor is right, move it to a separate table with the correct relationship and then you can keep the history.

Comment: Why is this a many to many between a user and a plan?
the exercise table is not a recording table, I have a seperate table that records the exercises

Comment: Why not using **enum PlanStatus** in PlanStatus property? Your current user's plan will have "InProgress" status set. If You delete that plan, You will set as InProgress another one. I think it's a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are the options as you outline, though I would suggest considering that the current plan is a consumption concern, not a data concern as the data already accommodates everything needed to determine it. The idea of adding a CurrentPlanId to User is a form of denormalization and it brings with it problems as there is no way to inherently enforce that the CurrentPlan references a plan with the correct status, or even a plan associated with that user at all. As far as the database and FK is concerned, it would just care that it references a row in the Plan table. The alternative is marking a plan as the "current" one, which you are effectively doing via the Status. The issue to face with this approach is regulating to ensure only a maximum of one Plan is recognized as the current one.

Within the entity you could have an unmapped property like:

```
[NotMapped]
public Plan? CurrentPlan
{
    get => Plans
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == PlanStatuses.InProgress); // I would generally recommend an OrderBy when using First vs. Single
}
```

The problem with this approach is that for it to work efficiently, the plans would need to be eager loaded. Otherwise you would trip lazy loading or a `NullReferenceException`. It also pollutes the entity with properties that you cannot use in Linq2SQL. For instance you cannot reference CurrentPlan in a `Where()` or `Select()` clause in a query prior to the query being materialized since EF cannot "see" it and translate it into SQL.

Which leads me to it being a consumption concern. When we are consuming data, whether to send data back from an API or present data on a UI, we should consider using dedicated classes for this purpose. A DTO or ViewModel, rather than the Entity. This way we can have a view model that includes a CurrentPlan, where the projection to that view model populates this based on the rules to determine what, if any, current plan their is. The viewModel is populated by a `Select()` or using a mapper that can work with EF's `IQueryable` implementation. In this way we would get:

```
var user = await _context.Users
    .Where(x => /* insert criteria */)
    .Select(x => new UserSummaryViewModel
     {
         UserId = x.UserId,
         // Other fields the view is consuming...
         CurrentPlan = x.Plans.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Status == PlanStatuses.InProgress);
     }).ToListAsync();
```

Mappers like Automapper can be configured with expressions for populating values that work within the `IQueryable` parsing, making the resulting query tidier:

```
var user = await _context.Users
    .Where(x => /* insert criteria */)
    .ProjectTo<UserSummaryViewModel>(config)
    .ToListAsync();
```

...where "config" is an instance of a mapper configuration containing the setup for how to build the view model from the entity(ies).

The advantages of using view models or DTOs rather than entities is that it both keeps entities pure to data concerns, and it will result in considerably more efficient queries compared to eager loading entire object graphs or tripping lazy loading. Designing around projection to separate data and consumption concerns can help address extracting rules like these without side-effects and lead to better performing applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two concepts into one, Entity and ViewModel, the "Current Plan" is not really an "entity" and it only consumes on the front end, which means the "Current Plan" should belong to the "ViewModel" instead of the "Entity"

This is similar to adding "Full Name" from "First" and "Last Name"